# how to replace null value(field) with word on CSV file

Tags: sed, awk

I have a comma separated CSV file looks like:

```
customer1,customer2,,customer4,

,customer2,,customer4,

custome1,,customer3,,
```

I want replace null value inside (,)with word "unknown".

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sed -e 's/,,/,unknown,/g'
```

will work except if you want to add unknown at the beginning or end of lines too.

If you also want to add something if the first is missing (line starts with `,`) or the last one is missing (line ends with `,`), then you could do:

```
sed -e 's/^,/unknown,/' -e 's/,,/,unknown,/g' -e 's/,$/,unknown/'
```

I'm sure there is a more elegant way, but that works.

Comment: thanks much! yeah the second one is work, the only thing I have missed on my question some of the lines have 2 or more null data. not at the end or beginning but on the middle. you code fixed for only one null data.would u help me with that.

Comment: sed -e 's/^,/unknown,/' -e 's/,,/,unknown,/g' -e 's/,,/,unknown,/g' -e 's/,$/,unknown/'
  and it's work. thank u so very much!!!