# Replace null values with '?' in a csv file (vi editor)

Tags: csv, replace, vi

I am trying to replace all `,,` with `,?,` in a csv file using vi editor. I run the command:

```
sed -i 's/^,/?,/' -i 's/,,/,?,/g' -i 's/,$/,?/' <filename>
```

but the command does not do it correctly. Does anyone know how I should change the command so it replaces all `,,` with `,?,` ? Thanks!

Comment: This might be a duplicate.  Check link.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5688231/how-to-replace-null-valuefield-with-word-on-csv-file

Comment: Here's another link to the same type of question.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6431573/replacing-consecutively-empty-values-in-a-csv-file

Comment: Sourced from the second link posted.  This works on the online emulator (changes made):    echo 'value,value,,,value,value' | sed -r 's/(^|,)(,|$)/\1?\2/g;s/(^|,)(,|$)/\1?\2/g'

Comment: It worked!!! Thanks a lot. But how can I change the file permanently? This only prints out the result.

Answer (score 0):

You can run below command to do the global find and replace

```
syntax - :%s/search_string/replacement_string/g
:%s/\,\,/\,?\,/g
```

Comment: I run that as well. It doesn't do what I want. I still have some ,,?,, in the result.

Comment: The output contains ?,,?,,?,, which is incorrect. I cannot have ,, !

Answer (score 0):

You can execute this in the terminal to get the desired output:

```
sed -i 's/^,/?,/; s/,,/,?,/g; s/,$/,?/' <filename>
```

Comment: I still have ,?,,?,,?,, kind of replacement in my output.